# Как заново отрисовать Яндекс.Карту (ObjectManager)?

Tags: yandex-maps-api, yandex-maps-jsapi

В форме использую карту из [примера](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsbox/2.1/object_manager), которая отображает точки в выбранном городе. Карта инициализируется методом `ymaps.ready(initYmaps)` при выборе города и сначала отображается нормально. Но если изменить город, происходит повторная инициализация и карта "отрисовывается" еще раз для нового города, а на странице после этого появляется вторая карта.

Подозреваю, что перед повторной инициализацией нужно удалить предыдущую карту. Как это сделать? Или для таких случаев предусмотрен другой подход?

**ОТРЕДАКТИРОВАНО**

Минимальный код, который воспроизводит поведение (без apikey):

#### index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Оптимальное добавление множества меток</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <script src="https://api-maps.yandex.ru/2.1/?lang=ru-RU&apikey=API_KEY" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="https://yandex.st/jquery/2.2.3/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="object_manager.js" type="text/javascript" defer></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <main>
      <select id="citySelect" class="form-control">
        <option>-- Выберите город --</option>
        <option value="1">Москва</option>
        <option value="2">Тоже Москва</option>
      </select>
      <div id="map" style="height: 500px;"></div>
    </main>
    <script>
      $("#citySelect").on("change", function (e) {
        ymaps.ready(init);
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

#### object_manager.js

```
function init () {
    var myMap = new ymaps.Map('map', {
            center: [55.76, 37.64],
            zoom: 10
        }, {
            searchControlProvider: 'yandex#search'
        }),
        objectManager = new ymaps.ObjectManager({
            // Чтобы метки начали кластеризоваться, выставляем опцию.
            clusterize: true,
            // ObjectManager принимает те же опции, что и кластеризатор.
            gridSize: 32,
            clusterDisableClickZoom: true
        });

    // Чтобы задать опции одиночным объектам и кластерам,
    // обратимся к дочерним коллекциям ObjectManager.
    objectManager.objects.options.set('preset', 'islands#greenDotIcon');
    objectManager.clusters.options.set('preset', 'islands#greenClusterIcons');
    myMap.geoObjects.add(objectManager);

    $.ajax({
        url: "http://localhost:5000/data.json"
    }).done(function(data) {
        objectManager.add(data);
    });

}
```

Comment: Покажите код с проблемой.

Comment: @flapenguin , добавил код.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не пересоздавайте карту и ObjectManager, а просто меняйте их центр и положение. Лучше всего разделить создание карты и обновление информации (первый показ = создание + обновление).

```js
var map = null;
var om = null;
ymaps.ready(function () {
  map = new ymaps.Map(...);
  om = new ymaps.ObjectManager(...);
  om.objects.options.set(...);
  om.clusters.options.set(...);
  map.getObjects.add(om);
  update();
});

$('#citySelect').on('change', update);

function update() {
  if (!map) return;
  var value = $('#citySelect').val();
  map.setCenter(...);
  map.setZoom(...);
  om.removeAll();
  // тут можно добавить отмену предыдущего запроса
  $.ajax(...).done(function (data) {
    if ($('#citySelect').val() === value) {
      om.objects.add(data);
    } else {
      // пока ждали ответ от сервера, пользователь уже выбрал другой город
      // можно проигнорировать, можно сохранить на будущее
      // просто показать их на карте нельзя: пользователь увидит
      // не выбранные город, а тот для которого данные пришли последними
      // (ну то есть технически можно, но это вряд ли желаемое поведение)
    }
  })
}
```